# broken permalinks in responsive layout

Tags: permalinks

In full view (when I can see all items in the top menu) my url to pages works well - the url is mypage.com/mysite. When I resize my window so I can see the drop-down top menu for pages, or see my page in my cell phone the pages links are broken. The links to my pages now does not contain page name but page id - mypage.com/111. Why would the behavior be different? This is very strange for me….

My hosting is on newarlyfreespeech. I have added .htaccess with correct premissions and save several times. I see that after saving permlink settings the file changes. .htaccess is located in the root of my wordpress install. Running WP 3.5.1 + theme should be also compatible with 3.5.1.

Any help more than appreciated.

Comment: Disable all plugins and switch to Twenty Twelve. Does it still happen? Also disable JavaScript. Resizing a window should not change the markup.

Comment: thanks, in Twenty Twelve the links work good. When I switch back to my theme the links are broken ;-(

Answer (score 0):

Your theme probably uses more than one menu - but which ones is visible depends on whether you are viewing the website on a big or a small screen. Check the source files and make sure the link is the same in both menus.

Comment: please, any hints that where I should start looking?

Comment: Can you post the URL of the site? Then I can tell you where to look.

Comment: So I managed to fix that thanks to you ;-). I didn't assign a menu in my template... thanks!